# How to send data using broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm sending a broadcast using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.android.name");
intent.putExtra("CODE", code);
```

in `onReceive` method of broadcast listener class when retrieving extra data using

```
String code = intent.getStringExtra("CODE");
```

I am getting null pointer exception.
Any help how to retrieve the data.

```
public class ReceiveNetworkBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String code = extras.getString("CODE");
        Log.e("NET_BCAST_RECEIVER: ", code); 

    }

}

       <receiver
            android:name=".ReceiveNetworkBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.android.name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

public void sendBroadcast(Context context, String code){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.android.name");
        intent.putExtra("CODE", code);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is code variable type string?

Comment: @nurisezgin yes, code is defined as String

Comment: Could you paste your all code. (AndroidManifest, Broadcast call and Broadcast receiver code)

Comment: @nurisezgin Codes added

Comment: Your code running successfully. Could you test fixed string? Maybe string null? ""intent.putExtra("CODE", "sampleData");""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get `Intent` extras in `bundle` like this :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     if (extras != null) {
      if(extras.containsKey("CODE")){
       Object value=extras.get("CODE");
       System.out.println(value);
      }
     }

}
```

Hope it will work now.